# explain query in LINQ in asp.net

Tags: c#, linq

I am start learning LINQ Technique and read this example in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx]

```
string sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
           // Split the string into individual words to create a collection. 
           string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

           // Using query expression syntax. 
           var query = from word in words
                       group word.ToUpper() by word.Length into gr
                       orderby gr.Key
                       select new { Length = gr.Key, Words = gr };

           // Using method-based query syntax. 
           var query2 = words.
               GroupBy(w => w.Length, w => w.ToUpper()).
               Select(g => new { Length = g.Key, Words = g }).
               OrderBy(o => o.Length);

           foreach (var obj in query)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Words of length {0}:", obj.Length);
               foreach (string word in obj.Words)
                   Console.WriteLine(word);
           }

           // This code example produces the following output: 
           // 
           // Words of length 3: 
           // THE 
           // FOX 
           // THE 
           // DOG 
           // Words of length 4: 
           // OVER 
           // LAZY 
           // Words of length 5: 
           // QUICK 
           // BROWN 
           // JUMPS
```

can any one explain the "query" for me ? and can u recommend a good place to learn LINQ online ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you words are in array called `words`.

```
from word in words
```

This statement means that you want one item of the array and this item will be called `word` in whole linq statement.

```
group word.ToUpper() by word.Length into gr
```

This is gonna be little bit harsh. Now, you are grouping word (converted to upper case) by its length and putting it into `gr` which represents `IGrouping<K,V>` objects - as you may see the `group` statement returns `IGrouping<K,V> objects`.

```
orderby gr.Key
```

This statements orders this grouped words by `Key` property represents the grouping value.

```
select new { Length = gr.Key, Words = gr }
```

By `select` statement you are able to determine what the whole LINQ will return. In this case it is gonna be `IEnumerable` of new objects with `Length` and `Words` properties.

I hope it helps you and I recommend you this [article](http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx).